# Skip-Gram Model Training

Tags: natural-language-processing, word2vec, word-embedding

Suppose we want to predict context words $w_{i-h}, \dots, w_{i+h}$ given a target word $w_i$ for a window size $h$ around the target word $w_i$. We can represent this as: $$p(w_{i-h}, \dots, w_{i+h}|w_i) = \prod_{-h \leq k \leq h, \ k \neq 0} p(w_{i+k}|w_i)$$ where we model the probabilities of a word $u$ given another word $v$ as $$p(u|v) = \frac{\exp(\left<\phi_u, \theta_v \right>)}{\sum_{u' \in W} \exp(\left<\phi_{u'}, \theta_v \right>)}$$ where $\phi_u, \theta_v$ are some vector representations for words $u$ and $v$ respectively and $\left<\phi_u, \theta_v \right>$ is the dot product between these vector representations (which represents some sort of similarity between the words) and $W$ is a matrix of all the words.

In Skip-Gram Negative Sampling, we want to learn the embeddings $\phi_u, \theta_v$ that maximize the following: $$\sum_{u \in W} \sum_{v \in W} n_{uv} \log \sigma(\left<\phi_u, \theta_v \right>) +k \mathbb{E}_{\bar{v}} \log \sigma(-\left<\phi_u, \theta_{\bar{v}} \right>)$$

> **Question.** How exactly does this work? For example, suppose $k=5$, the target word $w_i$ is $\text{apple}$ and we want to find
>   $p(\text{pie}| \text{apple})$. Let $n_{uv} = 10$ (number of times pie
>   co-occurs with apple). Then we sample $5$ random words $\bar{v}$ that
>   did not occur with $\text{apple}$ and whichever term in the sum is
>   bigger is the one we predict? For example, if the first term in the
>   sum is larger than the second term then we would predict that
>   $p(\text{pie}| \text{apple}) \approx 1$? Otherwise we predict that
>   $p(\text{pie}| \text{apple}) \approx 0$? Is this the correct
>   intuition?

**Source.** [Here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/language-processing/lecture/A4eQD/explicit-and-implicit-matrix-factorization) at around the 10:05 mark.

Answer (score 1):

Almost, but no. When you maximize that objective function, you do so by adjusting the parameters $\phi$ and $\theta$. After you're done with training, you can use your word embeddings for other NLP tasks. You don't, however, do any prediction directly from the skip-gram model.

To maximize the first term, co-occuring words must have large inner products. That is, they must be "similar". To maximize the second term**, the randomly sampled words must have a small inner product with $\phi_u$. That is, they must be "dissimilar" to $\phi_u$. Moving these word embeddings around in the vector space to make some words similar and others not is the only thing that happens during skip-gram training. 
$$$$

** $\sigma(-x)=1-\sigma(x)$, so maximizing $\sigma(-x)$ is minimizing $\sigma(x)$

Comment: But isn't the idea of using Skip-Gram to bypass the computational complexity of the log-likelihood maximization? So instead of predicting a word given another word, we are predicting whether certain words appear together or not (implicitly)? See 9:43 of the video.

Comment: No. But that idea is similar to one behind the [GloVe method](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf) of creating word embeddings. Also, I'm not really a fan of the video you keep linking. Higher quality videos from Stanford's 224d class are [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERibwqs9p38&list=PL3FW7Lu3i5Jsnh1rnUwq_TcylNr7EkRe6&index=2).

Comment: Why aren't you a fan of the video?